# Htaccess Querystring rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have URLs like
`/?test` that I want to rewrite to `/page.php?page=test`

I tried like this but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
RewriteRule ^\?([a-z0-9\-\+]{3,20})/?$ /page.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query string can only be tested with the [`RewriteCond` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). The [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) pattern is only tested against the [URL path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax) (in .htaccess files the URL path without the per-directory prefix).

So try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[a-z0-9-+]{3,20}$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /page.php?page=%0 [QSA]
```

Comment: Ah I see. It almost worked but the querystring page is empty when i'm trying to get it in page.php